# Lie Groups Homomrphism Question (Tangent Space)

Tags: abstract-algebra, differential-geometry, manifolds, lie-groups, tangent-spaces

I need to solve this:

> If $f:G\rightarrow H $ is a Lie group homomorphism, then
>   $T_{e_{1}}\ker(f)=\ker(df_{e_{1}})$

Here $e_{1}$ denotes the identity of $G$ and $df_{e_{1}}$ its the differential of $f$ at $e_{1}$.

Remembering that a Lie group homomorphism is a differentiable map ($C^{\infty}$) that is also a group homomorphism.

If anyone can help me, I'll be thankful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that you have the following commutative diagram :

$\require{AMScd} \begin{CD}
T_eG @>{df_e}>> T_eH\\ @V{\exp}VV @VV{\exp}V\\
G @>>{f}> H
\end{CD}$

Now if $df_e(X)=0$, then $df_e(tX) = 0$ for all $t$ so that $\exp(df_e(tX)) = 1$, therefore by commutativity of the above, $f(\exp(tX))=1$, so $\exp(tX)\in \ker(f)$ for all $t$; therefore $X\in T_e\ker(f)$.

Conversely, if $X\in T_e\ker(f)$, you can differentiate the equation $f(\exp(tX))=1$ at $t=0$ to get $df_e(X)=0$, so $X\in \ker(df_e)$.

Comment: Thanks! As I can see, this goes a bit further than the topics we saw so far in the discipline. Cuz we didn't defined such exp function yet. But I'll look forward, once your proof is very clean.

Comment: Can you try to adapt the proof by changing $\exp(tX)$ with $\gamma (t)$ where $\gamma$ is any path with derivative $X$ at $0$ ? (Which exists by definition of tangent space)

Comment: I'll try it. Thanks!